# Draw Overlay permission only asks first time when app is installed

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I'm developing a music player application. In which, I want to display a small floating button on screen for play/pause event when app is minimized(paused). (Functionality like face book messenger chat head). It works perfectly fine on devices which has SDK < 23. But in Device with SDK >= 23, It asks for permission  only 1st time when app in installed.

If permission is granted, it also perfectly displays floating button. But once the app is closed and again started, It is not showing floating button any more.

my code for opening permission dialogue box is:

```
public final static int REQUEST_CODE = 100;

public void checkDrawOverlayPermission() {
    /** check if we already  have permission to draw over other apps */
    if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        /** if not construct intent to request permission */
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        /** request permission via start activity for result */
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  Intent data) {
    /** check if received result code
     is equal our requested code for draw permission  */
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {

        if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            // continue here - permission was granted
            if(isServiceRunning != true){
                isServiceRunning = true;
                intent12 = new Intent(this,  notificationService.class);
                bindService(intent12, notificationConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                startService(intent12);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm displaying floating button when app is paused(when home button or back button is pressed to minimize the app). So I'm calling this `checkDrawOverlayPermission()` method in `onPause()` method of my apps mainActivity, like this:

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        checkDrawOverlayPermission();
    } else {
        if(isServiceRunning != true){
            isServiceRunning = true;
            intent12 = new Intent(this,  notificationService.class);
            bindService(intent12, notificationConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            startService(intent12);
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't understand what I'm  missing here. I think code for checking permission is ok because first time it displays floating button on the screen along with asking permission in a small dialogue. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything if the permission is already given in SDK > 23.
Add an else part to the `checkDrawOverlayPermission` method like this.

```
public void checkDrawOverlayPermission() {
    /** check if we already  have permission to draw over other apps */
    if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) { // WHAT IF THIS EVALUATES TO FALSE.
        /** if not construct intent to request permission */
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        /** request permission via start activity for result */
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    } else { // ADD THIS.
        // Add code to bind and start the service directly.
    }
}
```